# mongodb: Is it possible to do a range search on the first item in an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

Here is a simplified example of one record,

```
"id" : 1
"foo" : [
         [ 10:30,
           2,
           4
         ],
         [ 11:30,
           3,
           5
         ],
          ... 
        ]
```

foo is an array of arrays.

Is it possible to create a query to compare only the first element of each inner array using $gt and $lt to specify a range?

I know I can use $elemMatch to find an exact match,

db.collection.find('foo' : { $elemMatch : { $elemMatch : { $in : ['11:30'] } } } )

I would like to find all records that contain times between 10:00 and 12:00 as an example.

Comment: When you say "all the records" do you mean documents, i.e. that entire sample document is one record so it should be returned if at least one element matches, or do you mean you want to return the document with only the elemets of `foo` than match?

Comment: what kind of format `11:30` is this, is this a time?

Comment: @varman  Sorry, the format is not important, it was just to illustrate that the first element in the inner array is the only thing I want to check. It could be bob or 4 or anything. I want the query to only check the 0th element on the inner arrays.

Comment: @joe I want the whole record if any of the 0th elements of the inner arrays are within the range.

Comment: @tony the format is important to get ur result. Is it a string or number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this behavior using aggregation.

First use `$addfields` to create a new field using `$reduce` to iterate the outer array, and `$arrayElemAt` to select the element of the inner array, return the `$or` of the accumulator with the test of the current element.

Then `$match` the new field to select the documents with a matching value.

Note that if you want to be able to query for a range of times, you will need to either zero-pad hours less than 10, or use a date type.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields:{
      matches: {
        $reduce: {
           input: "$foo",
           initialValue: 0,
           in: {
             $cond: {
               if: {$eq: [
                          "11:30",
                          {$arrayElemAt: [ "$$this", 0]}
               ]},
               then: {$sum: ["$$value", 1]},
               else: "$$value"
             }
           }
        }
      }
  }},
  {$match: { matches: {$gt: 0}}
])
```